# CSS Selector for first TD except when containing a colspan

Tags: css, css-selectors

Lets say I have the following table:

```
<table style="width:500px">
 <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Now if I use the `first-child` selector to apply a style to the first TD, is there anyway I can have it ignore the td that has the colspan (even though of course this is the first-child)?

```
table tr td:first-child{
  width:100px;
}
```

I would be happy to give the td with the colspan it's own class name if there was then a way I could modify my selector to say `apply to first child except when the class name is x`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `:not([attr="val"])`

```
table tr td:first-child:not([colspan="#NUMBER OF COLSPAN"]){

    width:100px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table tr td:first-child:not(.ignore) {
  width:100px;
}
```

(Where you give the td that you want to ignore a class of "ignore")

Comment: Very elegant solution, but :not is only supported in ie9+

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give the class the opposing property?

```
table tr td:first-child{
    width:100px;
}

.your_class {
    width:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I could do that but I'd need to override a lot of styles. The example I provided was just for simplification but in reality I'd have around 20 css styles on that first column.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to just add a class to the first TD that you actually want to select:

```
<table style="width:500px">
 <tr>
    <td class='selectable'>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then hit it with:

```
table tr td.selectable {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could try jQuery and put a class name of "ignoreMe" on the row you don't want affected with:

```
$('table tr td:first-child').not('.ignoreMe').css({width:100});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example you can use `:not([colspan])` which ignores the any `td` with `colspan` defined. Something like this:

```
table tr td:first-child:not([colspan]){
    width:100px;
}
```